# ¿Cómo acelerar la rotación de un objeto?

Tags: html, css

Tengo que diseñar la rotación de un vinilo. Entiendo el concepto de las `@keyframes` pero lo que tengo es esto:

```css
button, button div {
  background-size: contain !important
}

button {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/xkpm1Cb.png);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2em
}

button div {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/r5IHWF3.png);
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}

img {
  animation: spin 1.8s linear infinite
}
```

```html
<button ontouchstart type="button">
  <div></div>
  <img alt="Vinilo de Gamba o calamar." height="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/lLVjsaE.png" width="250">
</button>
```

Quiero que el vinilo acelere de forma gradual.

Es decir, debe hacer lo siguiente:

- Que la velocidad de rotación pase de `0 RPM` a `33⅓ RPM` progresivamente
- Que se mantenga en esa velocidad durante `equis` segundos
- Tras `equis` segundos, reduzca de `33⅓ RPM` a 0 RPM de forma gradual, al igual que cuando aceleró

**TIP:**

> `33⅓ RPM` es equivalente a `1,8 s` ó `1,8 SPR` (segundos por revolución). Esto se consigue dividiendo `33⅓` entre `60 s` y dividiendo `1` por el resultado de la operación anterior.

No se me ocurre nada para "unir" dos funciones como `ease-in` y `linear`, por ejemplo, en una animación CSS. Si sirve de ayuda, [este sitio web](https://cubic-bezier.com) genera curvas bezier.

**AÑADO:**

Si no me equivoco, una función progreso-tiempo `linear` es equivalente a una función velocidad-tiempo `constante`, si le damos un tiempo de `1 s` al objeto para realizar el `@keyframes`:

[image: Comparación entre la función progreso-tiempo y velocidad-tiempo.]

Ahora, si quiero que tarde `1 s` de forma lineal en llegar a la velocidad velocidad máxima constante de `33⅓ RPM`, que se mantenga así por `10 s` y que posteriormente tarde `1 s` en decelerar de forma lineal hasta `0 RPM`, en una función velocidad-tiempo se vería así:

[image: Representación de una función velocidad-tiempo con los parámetros indicados arriba.]

La cuestión es cómo "traducir" de una función velocidad-tiempo a una función progreso-tiempo.

Comment: Hacer que ese cambio ocurra de forma progresiva será muy complicado. Si hacerlo de forma abrupta es una opción, mira esta [demostración](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/FuEL9/), aunque se basa en el evento hover puedes modificar eso facilmente.

Comment: Pues le he echado un vistazo y he estado jugando con los valores pero no he conseguido llegar a la solución...

Comment: Estuve analizando el problema y es bastante complejo hacerlo con CSS puro (no sé si se pueda hacer). Se puede obtener un resultado utilizando JavaScript combinado con CSS. Sin embargo, estoy investigando para intentar encontrar, al menos, una solución aproximada al problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hago es realizar 3 animaciones simulando una con puro CSS:

muestro animación de aceleración, la oculto para mostrar la rotación constante, y finalmente muestro encima la rotación de frenado al transcurrir el tiempo que se puede modificar en la variable global `--keep-spin-time`.

El planteamiento es:

- Primera animación, aceleración desde 0 hasta velocidad máxima
- Segunda animación, mantener velocidad máxima
- Tercera animación, deceleración desde velocidad máxima hasta 0

```css
:root {
  --rpm-freq: 1.8s;
  --rpm-freq-multiplier: 1.8;
  --keep-spin-time: 3s;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes fastHide {
  to {opacity: 0;}
}

#viniloSpinHide {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fastHide -1s;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {transform: rotate(1turn);}
}

img#keepSpin {
  animation: spin var(--rpm-freq) linear infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

img#acelerationSpin {
    animation: spin 1.8s ease-in;
}

#viniloSpinShow {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fastShow -1s;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--rpm-freq-multiplier) * var(--keep-spin-time));
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes fastShow {
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

img#decelerationSpin {
  animation: spin 2.3s ease-out;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--rpm-freq-multiplier) *  var(--keep-spin-time));
}
```

```html
<img id="keepSpin" alt="Vinilo de Gamba o calamar." height="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/lLVjsaE.png" width="250">
<div id="viniloSpinHide">
  <img id="acelerationSpin" alt="Vinilo de Gamba o calamar." height="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/lLVjsaE.png" width="250">
</div>
<div id="viniloSpinShow">
  <img id="decelerationSpin" alt="Vinilo de Gamba o calamar." height="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/lLVjsaE.png" width="250">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear varias clases CSS para cambiar el tiempo de animación y jugar un poco con los tiempos. El único problema que veo con esto es el salto que da en cada cambio, probablemente pueda solucionarse agregando más clases, es cuestión de probar.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#start');
let img = button.querySelector('img');
// Esta variable es útil para asignar las clases
let start = 20;
// Con esta se trata de que los tiempos no sean iguales entre cada cambio
let time = 20;
function rotate() {
    // Solo si es mayor o igual que cero, de lo contrario, la clase no es válida
    if(start >= 0) {
        // Asignar clase
        img.className = 'rotate' + start;
        // Crear espera
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Reducir tiempo y clase
            time -= 3;
            start -= 5;
            // Ejecutar nuevamente
            rotate();
        }, time * 100);
    }
}
// Activar rotación
button.addEventListener('click', rotate);
```

```css
button, button div {
  background-size: contain !important
}

button {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/xkpm1Cb.png);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2em
}

button div {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/r5IHWF3.png);
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
/* Crea tantas clases como sea necesario solo cambiando el tiempo */
img.rotate20 { animation: spin 20s linear infinite }
img.rotate15 { animation: spin 15s linear infinite }
img.rotate10 { animation: spin 10s linear infinite }
img.rotate5 { animation: spin 5s linear infinite }
img.rotate0 { animation: spin 1.8s linear infinite }
```

```html
<button id="start">
  <div></div>
  <img alt="Vinilo de Gamba o calamar." height="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/lLVjsaE.png" width="250">
</button>
```

Sería más fácil si desde Javascript se pudiera modificar el tiempo de la animación, pero no encontré la forma de lograrlo.